# PHP: Perform operation on all array elements but the first and last

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I know I could use `array_slice()` to create a new array of all but the first & last elements, perform operations on each, and then tack the original first and last values back on. That seems like overkill though. Is there a cleaner way to perform an operation (in this case, just appending and prepending strings to the array values) on all interior array elements and not on the ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something, but wouldn't this do the trick?

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++) {
   // Do stuff to $arr[$i], like prefixing and suffixing
   $arr[$i] = 'prefix ' . $arr[$i] . ' suffix';
}
```

Comment: It might not if OP is using an associative array, but in that case order is rather weird anyways.

Comment: If it's an associative array, and it's been sorted, they can do the same thing. Just get `array_keys($arr)[$i]` inside the loop and then act on the item with that key.

Comment: That keeps setting $i back to 1, so altering `$arr[i]` only ever affects `$arr[1]`;

Comment: It seems to be printing `$arr[1]` only, but printing it `count($arr)-2` times.

Comment: `for ($i = 1; $i < count($breadcrumb) - 1; $i++) {
        print($breadcrumb[$i]);
    }` gives me $breadcrumb[1] printed out three times, for a five-element $breadcrumb array.

Comment: Do a `print_r($breadcrumb)` before going into the `for` loop to ensure that what you think is in the array actually is.  The `for` loop code is correct, so something else must be wrong.

Comment: Right you are! Sorry for doubting you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways. One would be:

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++) {
    // process $arr[$i];
}
```

If your array is associative, and has been sorted in some meaningful way, you can do this:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
for($i = 1; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++) {
    // process $arr[$keys[$i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
reset($array);
$firstKey = key($array);
end($array);
$lastKey = key($array);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === $firstKey || $key === $lastKey) {
         continue;
    }
    do_your_stuff($key, $value);
 }
```